upward downward topdown bottomup causation
can u tell me more about upward and downward causation . Is it same as bottom up and top down causation. What about one cause having lot of effects and one effect having lot of causes ?
Any chart/diagram to see the connection between upward, downward, forward, backward, convergent, divergent causation....
Any connection or map to comprehend everything

Yes, it is the same, see Downward causation. One cause having a lot of effects and one effect having a lot of causes has nothing to do with it and is the usual way of things.

There's also circular causation: feedback loops, vicious circles and the likes.

When you think about it, all causes have an infinite number of effects, and all effects have an infinite number of causes.
This is because it is impossible to complete isolate any part of the universe (like a lab) from other parts of the universe. Therefore what happens in the lab at any time is a result of a whole universe of causes. In practice scientists make do by simplifying reality and isolating their labs from germs, from microseisms, or from strong fluctuations in moisture and temperature that could affect their results. But they know from their thermodynamic classes that in principle, there is no such thing as a closed system. There are only approximations of it.
In principle, the whole universe impacts the whole universe, at all times and of all eternity. The chain of causes and effects is (near?) infinite towards the past and towards the future. It's an abstraction to say: "Cause C led to Effect E". Not just because C cannot in principle be taken in isolation as the one-and-only cause of E in the whole universe, but also because C itself had prior causes, and E itself will have future effects. The clock keeps ticking.
So these neat little arrows in our diagrams are always and by necessity gross simplifications of far more complex webs of stuff happening. And sometimes they are useful simplications in that they give us a degree of control. They work well enough.
As for downward or upward causation, these are evidently metaphors. There is no literal up or down there, as meaning "closer to or further away from the center of the earth". In this metaphor, "down" and "up" stand for "smaller" and "larger", respectively.
So the idea of "upward causation" is that anything happening to an element of a system (say, a piston breaks in the engine of a car) may have effects at the level of the whole system (the whole car will stop, not just the broken piston).
The idea of "downward causation" is that living systems (cells, organs, organisms, biotopes) are able to "act as wholes". The general state of the system (say, my body's temperature rises) can cause stuff to happen at a sub-system level (my skin starts to sweat).
Of course, these are just gross simplifications of far more complex webs of stuff, as usual, but they can be useful simplifications. They can satisfactorily explain why the car stopped or why I'm sweating.

+1, Good answer; these are the 1000 words of my diagrams...

@IoannisPaizis Thanks. Part of my job involves drawing causality diagrams. Less is more in this domain.

Requested diagrams:

GOD (simplified version)



TAO (a more abstract one)



Thanks for addding diagrams, but could you please explain them.

@Geoffrey Thomas, by reading the other answer (Olivier5) (at least the first two sentences), it's obvious that causality links or interrelates all phenomena in the universe: This interrelatedness is in the core of both west-religions ex. God and East ex. Tao.

@Geoffrey Thomas, so these diagrams mean that the only way to understand the "connection between upward, downward, forward, backward, convergent, divergent causation" is in the context of a totality by whatever means one has to conceive it, ex. God, Tao.

@IoannisPaizis how can u picturize God

The "causational" (in the context of this topic) inter-relationship of all existing things.
